# Не компилируется код загрузчика

Tags: ассемблер, fasm, загрузчик

зашел на статью про написание начального загрузчика на fasm. статья и исходники: https://subscribe.ru/archive/comp.soft.myosdev/201207/01022505.html . не компилируется загрузчик. вот ошибка:

```
flat assembler  version 1.73.09  (16384 kilobytes memory)
bootloader.asm [17]:
 @:
processed: @:
error: symbol already defined.
```

у автора почему-то компилируется. что нужно сделать, чтобы это собралось?

Comment: У автора при публикации в web пропали имена меток. Видите, там переходы идут по разным меткам вроде `@b`, `@f` и т.п. а таких меток нет. зато просто `@:` встречается несколько раз, чего быть не может. Вам надо изучить алгоритм и расставить правильные имена меток

Comment: уже решил. нужно указывать в имени меток @@.

Answer (score 1):

В коде по ссылке вместо "безымянных" меток `@@:` почему-то стоят метки `@:`.

Пример :

```
...
    push ax si
    mov ah, 0x0E
@:
    lodsb
    test al, al
    jz @f
    int 0x10
    jmp @b
@:
    pop si ax
    ret
...
```

Должно быть:

```
...
    push ax si
    mov ah, 0x0E
@@:
    lodsb
    test al, al
    jz @f ; переход на ближайшую следующую метку @@
    int 0x10
    jmp @b ; переход на ближайшую предыдущую @@
@@:
    pop si ax
    ret
...
```

Безымянные метки позволяют не плодить именованные метки (насколько это повышает или ухудшает читаемость - другой вопрос). Переход на ближайшую предыдущую безымянную метку происходит по имени `@b` (например, `jmp @b`), на ближайшую следующую - по имени `@f`.